# Most efficient way of downloading large amounts of data to android?

Tags: android

I have an external database on Azure that holds large amounts of information. My app needs to be able to synchronize a selection of this data and store it locally on the app's database. I currently use web services to make calls to the database. When the app starts for the first time, it will have a large amount of data that would need to be downloaded. What's the most efficient way of downloading a large number of rows from the external database? I was thinking an XML file might be the best way, but I'm not sure. There could be thousands of rows that need downloading so I'm not sure which method would be the most appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't 300 ways to download data, so you'll basically have to call your API and get the data. For obvious performance reasons, I would avoid XML and prefere JSON instead. So once you've got your JSON file, you parse it and put it in the locale database. I also would suggest you to use service as it won't be interupt, and don't forget to warn the user that you gonna download massive data ;)

If you wan't to minimize the amount of data downloaded, you can store a JSON file for example in the assets that will contains all the things "static" that won't change online.

Comment: Thanks, I was going to use XML but I'll try JSON instead.

Comment: You're welcome. In my opinion JSON is way more appropriate to transport object over network than XML. It's lighter, it's simpler to parse into object and there are very efficient library to parse automatically. For you architecture, If you want, you can take a look at Jackson for parsing in Android and at Jersey if you want a JAVA REST API. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would offload the work to some sort of [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). Services have the benefit of running in the background without interacting with the application. You would still need to create another thread to do the work. When the download is finished, it will simply destroy itself.

Comment: Sorry, I think you've misunderstood my question. I'm asking about the actual method of downloading the data, not the structure of the app - I've got that sorted already. I am using a background service for the day-to-day synchronization of the app - but when the app starts for the first time, it won't have any data - and **must** download the necessary data from the main server before proceeding - so the initial sync will be done in a background thread inside an activity.

Comment: Ahh, okay. You can send the data as a file, as JSON/XML with an HTTP Request, or you can get it in chunks in case there is any network error at any point where you can then restart where you left off.

Answer (score 0):

Data should be downloaded anyway whatever method you use, maybe you may prepare the initial data as XML file, download it the first time and store the data in the database showing a progress bar to the user